# (Combinatorial) Game Theory: Determinacy and Determinism

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, infinite-games

I am struggling with the concepts of Determinacy and Determinism.
Are the following statements correct(for 2-player, zero-sum games)?
Or am I getting something mixed up in my head?

A game has the property **determinancy**, if one player has a winning strategy.

A game is ***deterministic***, if a game ends in a finite amount of steps.

A game is ***deterministic***, if a game does not contain any element of chance.

A game where player L always wins(and player R always looses) after an infinite amount of steps, has the property **determinancy**, but is not ***deterministic***.

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: There are infinite deterministic games.  All "deterministic" means is that there is no chance associated with any move.  Rolling a die, say, would be a non-determinsitic game move.

Comment: For instance:  imagine two players choose digits sequentially for some real number between $0$ and $1$.  One player wins if the number is rational, the other wins if it is irrational.  That's an infinite deterministic game which also has determinancy (the irrational player can always force a win).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A game is **determined** if one player has a winning strategy. ("Has the determinacy property" seems like it should mean this, too.)

A game is **terminating**/**non-loopy** if it ends in finitely many steps/turns (even though there may be no bound on the number).

A game is **deterministic** if there is no element of chance.

As you mention, a game could be determined without being terminating.